# How can you detected in a mariadb prepared that no rows are found in a select statement

Tags: mariadb

What is a good way to detected that now rows are found in a mariadb prepared statement with a select,
because I can not use the function FOUND_ROWS(). According to the mariadb documentation the FOUND_ROWS() function is not affected when no rows are returned.
I now use mariadb version 10.11.6

A read the mariadb documentation and searched the internet, but could not find good examples.

Here is some extra information.

From the the following piece of code I want to now if it returns no records. How can I detect that?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test.stmt_test(IN col_name VARCHAR(64), IN tab_name VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ‘, col_name, ‘  FROM  ', tab_name);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    # how do I detect, there are no records returned?
END;
```

Comment: I believe the documentation you are referring to ... *Statements which don't return any results don't affect FOUND_ROWS() - the previous value will still be returned* ... is about things like UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT queries - these are statements that return no rows. SELECT statements are row-returning statements which just happen to return zero rows (if that makes sense). If you need further help, give more context - generally you know if a query returns no rows because you don't get any rows back :) So you can check rowcounts, yes, but also you can simply just check if you have any rows.

Comment: On SQL level you cannot determine if a select statement returns zero, one or more rows without executing an additional (expensive) statement like `SELECT COUNT(*) ... `.  Determining the number of rows is handled by client when processing result set.

Comment: I know that I have to use count(*) to determine how many records a query can give. But in my real programma I have to differently after the execute statement depending of there are rows returned or not. The code I add is just to simplify and to point where I want act.

Comment: I tried FOUND_ROWS before and after DEALLOCATE but it did nog give the right count. If query returns no rows FOUND_ROWS does not return 0 as a result.

Comment: [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/dxOkNsTH)

Answer (score 1):

What language is invoking the query?

In many languages (PHP, Perl, etc), you simply count the number of rows returned.  Zero means no rows.

`FOUND_ROWS` is not relevant to this discussion; it is used for something else.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution by my self inspired by Georg Richter. You can not use FOUND_ROWS() to determine the amount of returned records by a prepared statement. But if you use a INTO clause with a user variable it works.

```
SET @n=0;
# Create a query which return more than 1 records
# Based on sample data this query should return 3 records
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT count(*) into @n FROM myTable where id >= 14 and id <= 16'); 
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt; 

select @n;
```

Then @n returns the amount returned records.